# Issue with next js site deployment (production mode)

Tags: next.js, deployment

I have a nextjs application. its hosted on Ubuntu OS.

When I run, npm run start or npm start, the application runs.

but when the terminal is closed, service stops and site gets down.

On same server, I also have an express application. I am using pm2 to start the express server.

But when I try to run next application using PM2, it shows status as errored and does not start.

I tried using npm commands and pm2. but didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a Next.js application with PM2 requires some additional configuration, especially if you are using the npm start command.

1.Install PM2 globally if you haven't already: npm install -g pm2

2.Create an ecosystem file for PM2. You can manually create a pm2.config.js file or use the ecosystem.config.js

3. Replace /path/to/your/next/app with the actual path to your Next.js application.
4. Start your Next.js application with PM2:pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am using pm2 with ecosystem.config.js. Now I am getting the below error. 

Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/html/project/'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []

Comment: Open your ecosystem.config.js file and verify the paths specified for the script property. Ensure that the path is correct and points to a valid Node.js script

module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'your-app-name',
      script: '/path/to/your/app.js', // Check this path
      // Other configurations...
    },
  ],
};

Comment: In logs I am getting  - 
You are using Node.js 18.13.0. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required. 
when I do, node -v, I get v18.17.0